# How can I use the normal (desktop) Gmail on an iPad?

Tags: gmail, ipad

When I use Gmail on the iPad via Safari, I get a -to me- unusable version of Gmail like the image below:

[image]

**Is there a way I can get the normal desktop view on my iPad?**

(Note: the bottom row as shown in the screenshot, to switch view, is not there for me.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the reasons you find it unusable?

Comment: For one, no access to contacts.

Comment: I want to change my imap preferences. The special ipad app view doesnt have that.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [apple.se].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scroll the inbox side of the client and there is a link to the desktop which will get you to the more familiar Gmail view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I wanted. In the meantime I've also quite adapted to the mobile version, but I think this will help me more.

Comment: Thanks, I needed that to make my gMail Gadgets and Marketplace Apps work!

Comment: This no longer works AFAICT

Comment: @gman, yes it does, I've made an edit to show where the link is now.

Comment: @crclayton: Are you sure it's still the "inbox side of the client" that you need to scroll, as the answer (you've added a screenshot to) states. The mobile version on Android (and your screenshot) appears to show the links at the bottom of the labels column (left side)?

Comment: I believe that left hand side column is what James was referring to as the inbox side of the client. In the original picture, the left column is labeled inbox, whereas the right is what I'd call the message side.

Answer (score 9):

**Is there any way to get the normal desktop view on my iPad?**

You can force the simple HTML mode using https://mail.google.com/mail/h/

You used to be able to force Standard mode using http://mail.google.com/mail?nocheckbrowser, but this no long seems to work on iPad.

Comment: I primarily use the HTML mode in the iCab browser. It's definitely not as nice as the desktop version, but when I've tried that, it doesn't seem to work right on the iPad. Wish it did and it seems like the iPad should be able to handle it. Having gmail in the browser is nice when accessing other web pages that link with google. And I use the stars for tagging important items.

Comment: The “Simple HTML mode” link (which has been deprecated) now loads the standard version, which is what I wanted. Thanks!